# Проблема с реализацией поиска по listview в фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Делал что-то типа словаря под андроид. Присутствовал listview и поиск по элементам listview. Но пришлось добавить шаблон navigation drawer и соответственно поместить этот код в фрагмент draver-а. Все отлично работало (listview) пока не решил добавить поиск. С этого момента при переходе в фрагмент приложение вылетает. Помогите пожалуйста!

FirstFragment

```
package com.example.ogyrec.dictionary;

import ...


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    String[] items = new String[]{"...", "...", "..."};

    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView2, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });*/

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
                i.putExtra("names", itemValue);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    /*public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            String textToSearch1 = textToSearch.toLowerCase();

            if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch1)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }*/
}
```

Поиск закомментирован

Так же создан list_item.hml если надо

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Вот, что пишет android monitor

```
05-22 23:36:14.889 26912-26912/com.example.arseny.songbook3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.arseny.songbook3, PID: 26912
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                                                                                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2039)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1197)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1403)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1085)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5909)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main
```

Возможно, что глупый вопрос задаю, но все же помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: В ошибке написано, что невозможно выполнить метод setText() для нулевой (null) ссылки. Но в представленном коде, видимо, ошибочной строки нет.

Comment: приложите код строки на которую ссылаются логи, и отредактируйте вывод логов чтобы он адекватно выглядел, так же приложите код активности/фрагмента где происходит падение если этот код не приложен

Answer (score 0):

Вам лог показывает, что у вас возникает NullPointerException

java.lang.***NullPointerException***: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.***TextView.setText***(java.lang.CharSequence)' ***on a null object reference***

У вас есть TextView в list_item.xml, но вы его не создавали/определяли и пытаетесь использовать его метод setText(), поэтому лог и ругается

Я не нашла, где вы пытаетесь вызывать этот метод, но могу предположить, что он в адаптере

Прилагаю пример того, как у меня это организовано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]